# usort() not working after array

Tags: php, usort

My code is as follows

```
$results = array();
$results[] = json_decode("json api response url", true);
$results[] = json_decode("json api response url 2", true);
$results[] = json_decode("json api response url 3", true);
foreach($results as $result) {
     $decoded = $result['Info'];
     usort($decoded, function($a, $b) { return $a['price'] > $b['price'] ? 1 : -1; });
     foreach($decoded as $row) {
         echo $row['price'];
     } 
}
```

JSON array is returned as follows

```
["Info"]=>
[0]=>
array(13) {
  ["price"]=>  
    int(3000)
} 
[1]=>
array(13) {
  ["price"]=>
     int(5000)
```

it's doing a `usort` for every `json_decode` reponse instead of all of them together, is their a way around this or not ?

Comment: Remove it from the loop.

Comment: Merge your three data arrays into one before sorting.

Comment: unrelated: `json_decode("json api response url"), true);` There are too much closing brackets in there (and also the other two lines)

Comment: Can you show me some example output?

Comment: @Husman done as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do, is to concatenate all of the JSON responses and put them together, instead of creating 3 different array elements in results[]; Look into array_merge():

```
$result = array();
$arr1 = json_decode("json api response url", true);
$arr2 = json_decode("json api response url 2", true);
$arr3 = json_decode("json api response url 3", true);

$result = array_merge($arr1['Info'], $arr2['Info'], $arr3['Info']);

$decoded = $result;
usort($decoded, function($a, $b) { return $a['price'] > $b['price'] ? 1 : -1; });
foreach($decoded as $row) {
  echo $row['price'];
}
```

Comment: any small examples please ?

Comment: You might have to play around with the array formats. try my edited code above.

Comment: try print_r($result) to see what the array looks like, it should just be one big array, not a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

You are performing a usort on every item inside the array. Try to do the usort before you loop over the results. I have no idea if this will work, but it should point you to the right direction.

```php
$results = array();
$results[] = json_decode("json api response url", true);
$results[] = json_decode("json api response url 2", true);
$results[] = json_decode("json api response url 3", true);

usort($results, function($a, $b) {
  return $a['Info']['price'] > $b['Info']['price'] ? 1 : -1;
});

foreach($results as $result) {
   // do your looped stuff
}
```

Comment: @Anyone check the number of closing parenthesis on the json_decode statement. You have one too many.

Comment: No idea where they came from, fixed.

Comment: Thanks , this helped me sort my array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = array();
$results[] = json_decode("json api response url", true);
$results[] = json_decode("json api response url 2", true);
$results[] = json_decode("json api response url 3", true);

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($results, "cmp");

foreach($results as $row) {
   echo $row['price'];
}
```